# not able to configure image for prediction in ResNetV2 model trained using transfer learning

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I trained a ResNetV2 model for face recognition and got a validation accuracy of about 90%. I am using 320 grayscale images from 40 classes for training. I am unable to preprocess the image so as to use model.predict() function. I did not use preprocess_input function because I was getting a low accuracy when using that to train the model. Please help

```
base_model = ResNet50V2(weights='imagenet',include_top=False,input_shape=(224, 224,3))
# don't train existing weights
for layer in base_model.layers:
  layer.trainable = False

x=base_model.output
x=GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x=Dense(1024,activation='relu')(x) #dense layer 1
x=Dropout(0.2)(x)
preds=Dense(40,activation='softmax')(x) #final layer with softmax activation
model=Model(inputs=base_model.input,outputs=preds)
model.summary()

from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
                                   shear_range = 0.2,
                                   zoom_range = 0.2,
                                   horizontal_flip = True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)

training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(train_path,
                                                 target_size = (224,224),
                                                 batch_size = 8,
                                                 class_mode = 'categorical')

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(valid_path,
                                            target_size = (224,224),
                                            batch_size = 8,
                                            class_mode = 'categorical')

model.compile(optimizer='Adam',loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])

training = model.fit(
  training_set,
  validation_data=test_set,
  epochs=40,
  steps_per_epoch=8
)

img = image.load_img('/content/9.pgm.jpg.jpg', target_size=(224,224,3))
pixels = image.img_to_array(img)
pixels = pixels.astype('float32')
pixels /= 255.0
model.predict(pixels)
```

Edit: the code used for preprocessing, which I eventually discarded was -

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.applications.resnet50 import preprocess_input
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=preprocess_input)

training_set = datagen.flow_from_directory(train_path,
                                                 target_size = (224,224),
                                                 batch_size = 8,
                                                 class_mode = 'categorical')

test_set = datagen.flow_from_directory(valid_path,
                                            target_size = (224,224),
                                            batch_size = 8,
                                            class_mode = 'categorical')
```

Comment: You say preprocessing the images caused low accuracy. Did you use tf.keras.applications.resnet.preprocess_input as the preprocessing function? This should make your model work better not worse. Please show the code you used when trying to use the preprocessing function

Comment: @GerryP I have updated the code, have a look.

Comment: The code you had for preprocessing looks right. Can't understand why it would cause low accuracy. One concern is you say you have 320 gray scale images and 40 classes. So you only have a total of 320 images?  That's only 8 images per class. Image augmentation will help but this is very few samples for your network to train on. Can you show the training data per epoch (with and then without preprocessing)? Also what is your problem with predictions? Do you get an error code?

Comment: Also it is best for the test set to set shuffle=False in flow_from_directory. Also if you have batch_size=8 and you have 320 images then in model.fit set the steps_per_epoch=40

Comment: also if your images are grayscale then is flow_from_directory you should set color_mode='grayscale'

Answer (score 1):

The correct code to be used for prediction is as below:

```
from PIL import Image
from tensorflow.keras.utils import load_img

class_names=['daisy', 'dandelion', 'roses', 'sunflowers', 'tulips']

img = tf.keras.utils.load_img('./dataset/rose_test.jpeg', target_size=(224,224))
pixels =tf.keras.utils.img_to_array(img)
pixels=tf.expand_dims(pixels, 0)
#pixels = pixels.astype('float32')
pixels /= 255.0
pred = model.predict(pixels)  # as I have used 5 classes dataset
pred
```

Output:

```
array([[1.0110709e-07, 6.0101044e-08, 9.4008398e-01, 4.7367696e-08,
        5.9915919e-02]], dtype=float32)
```

To get class name of loaded image:

```
print(class_names[np.argmax(p)])
```

Output:

```
roses
```